# ERROR: Specified HTML directory '/home/jenkins/agent/...../site/jacoco' does not exist And No test report files were found. Configuration error?

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, build, pipeline, jacoco

I am very new to pipelines and I am trying to run a pipeline and at this stage [Pipeline] publishHTML receive the following error:

Specified HTML directory '/home/jenkins/agent/....site/jacoco' does not exist.

And at the stage [Pipeline] junit:

No test report files were found. Configuration error?

I would like to tell Jenkins to not look for a test class (there is not one), to skip the above two so that it continues in the pipeline.

Is this possible ? If yes, how?

Thank you

Tried junit allowEmptyResults: true, testResults: ".../reports/*.xml" but the above two errors are still displayed.